# What I need to write in these places in code in Redux app(remake pure react to redux)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have app wrote on `pure React` where I make request to server and get response - `category list`.This list I can filter using `query params` in url. Value for these parameters I take from the state. I needed to rework small part of my React app to Redux. But I just started learn redux, that is, in some places in my redux code I don't know what I need to write.

#### Small part my React app (before I remake to Redux):

```
const Home = () => {
    
const [value, setValue] = useState({
    listCategory: [],
    currentPage: 1, 
    buttonsPagination: 0,   
    searchInput: ""
});

// Here useEffect and fetch function, but I dont write it, because it not related with my question

  const changePage = (argPage) => {    
    setValue((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      currentPage: argPage,
    }));};

  const upadateStateSearchInput = (event) => {         
     setValue({
        ...value,
        searchInput: event.target.value,
        currentPage:1
    });};

return ( 
<div>
     {[...Array(value.buttonsPagination)].map((item, index) => (
          <button key={'listCategory' + index}   
                  onClick={() => changePage(index + 1)}>{index + 1}
          </button>   ))}

     <input type="text" onChange={upadateStateSearchInput} value={value.searchInput} />
</div>
);}
```

### Below I will write what I was able to do myself - according to my current knowledge in Redux. What I needed to write instead these - `/*.......*/`?

## What already could to do myself in Redux:

```
// action
const changePage = (/*.......*/) => ({
    type: "CHANGE_PAGE",
    payload: /*.......*/
});

const upadateStateSearchInput = (/*.......*/) => ({
    type: "UPDATE_SEARCHINPUT",
    payload: /*.......*/
});

//reducer
const initialState = {
  listCategory: [],
  currentPage: 1,
  buttonsPagination: 0,
  searchInput: "",
  isLoading: false 
};

export function filterList(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_PAGE":
      return {
        ...state,
        /*.......*/ 
      };
    case "UPDATE_SEARCHINPUT":
      return {
        ...state,
        /*.......*/
      };
    case "LOAD_DATA_START":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true 
      };
    case "LOAD_DATA_END": {
      const { payload } = action;
      return {
        ...state,
        listCategory: payload.data,
        currentPage: payload.page,
        buttonsPagination: Math.ceil(payload.total / payload.perPage),
        isLoading: false 
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

{[...Array(value.buttonsPagination)].map((item, index) => (
          <button key={/*...........*/}   
                  onClick={/*.........*/}>{/*.........*/}
          </button>   ))}

     <input type="text" onChange={/*........*/} value={/*........*/} />

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  const listCategory = useSelector(state => state.filterListReducer.listCategory);
  const currentPage = useSelector(state => state.filterListReducer.currentPage);
  const searchInput = useSelector(state => state.filterListReducer.searchInput);
  const buttonsPagination = useSelector(state => state.filterListReducer.buttonsPagination);

  const rootReducer = combineReducers({
     filterListReducer: filterList,
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// actions.js
export const changePage = (argPage) => ({
    type: "CHANGE_PAGE",
    payload: argPage
});

export const upadateStateSearchInput = (event) => ({
    type: "UPDATE_SEARCHINPUT",
    payload: event.target.value
});

//reducer.js
const initialState = {
  listCategory: [],
  currentPage: 1,
  buttonsPagination: 0,
  searchInput: "",
  isLoading: false 
};

export function filterList(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_PAGE":
      return {
        ...state,
       currentPage: action.payload
      };
    case "UPDATE_SEARCHINPUT":
      return {
        ...state,
        currentPage: 1,
        searchInput: action.payload  
      };
    case "LOAD_DATA_START":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true 
      };
    case "LOAD_DATA_END": {
    const {payload}=action;
      return {
        ...state,
        listCategory: payload.data,
        currentPage: payload.page,
        buttonsPagination: Math.ceil(payload.total / payload.perPage),
        isLoading: false 
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

//App.js
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {changePage, upadateStateSearchInput} from 'actions';

const App = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const filterList = useSelector(state => state.filterListReducer)
    return (
        <div>
            {[...Array(filterList.buttonsPagination)].map((item, index) => (
                <button key={'listCategory' + index}
                        onClick={() => dispatch(changePage(index + 1))}>{index + 1}
                </button>))
            }
            <input type="text" onChange={(event)=> dispatch(upadateStateSearchInput(event))} value={filterList.searchInput}/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I have couple remark for you: 1) Why you wrote `currentPage: argPage` in `{}`. See `LOAD_DATA_END`. There I dont write in `{}`  2) Why you pass `{type,payload}` instead `action`? It must be one code writing style. In terms of my task is better since I wrote in my option because in your option case `LOAD_DATA_START` will no longer work 3) Why you wrote `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` if I already use `useSelector` and `useDispatch`. Scroll through my redux code below. You probably did not see what is at the bottom of the code. I need in my app use `useSelector` and `useDispatch`.

Comment: I have updated the code to match your writing style

Comment: Thank you very much! I will test your code and write to you if everything works fine in a few minutes

Comment: `Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.` in this line:
`onClick={() => dispatch(changePage(index + 1))}>{index + 1}`

Comment: I have just tested the code localy  and it works.
Can you make sure that the functions changePage and upadateStateSearchInput are imported from actions.js and are written corretcly.

Comment: I checked. Yes, functions `changePage` and `upadateStateSearchInput` are imported from `actions.js` corretcly

Comment: Try again to compare the codes. If it still doesn't wanna work,
onClick={() => dispatch({
    type: "CHANGE_PAGE",
    payload: index+1
})}>{index + 1}
should work.

Comment: Yes now work. So somewhere in some file I wrote something wrong. I can give you a screenshot to make some file from my text editor. What is file make screenshot for you?

Comment: I fixed this error. I just forgot remove React method from App.js file. Now I will test action upadateStateSearchInput. But my input located in file Search.js and look like this:
`export default ({ value, userEnteredValue}) => {
  return (
    <div className="search">
        <input type="text"  onChange={userEnteredValue} value={value}/>
    </div>
  );
};`and in App.js I have children component in return: `<Search value={value.searchInput} 
             userEnteredValue={upadateStateSearchInput} 
      />`What I need to change in search.js and in return App.js?

Comment: This input in file Search.js: `<input type="text" onChange={(event)=> dispatch(upadateStateSearchInput(event))} value={filterList.searchInput}/>` I just wanted to write my question to make less code but as it turned out it was a bad idea because now i don't know how to correctly write the code in file Search.js and in the `App.js ` file in return.

Comment: You can leave Search.js as is it.
`export default ({ value, userEnteredValue}) => { return ( <div className="search"> <input type="text" onChange={userEnteredValue} value={value}/> </div> ); };`
In App.js
`...
return (
<Search value={value.searchInput} userEnteredValue={(event)=> dispatch(upadateStateSearchInput(event))} />
)`

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: can you tell me how to remake one more function into redux? `const deleteСoupleСategory = (argDeleteCoupleCategory) => { setValueB({ ...valueB, numberCoupleIdDelete: [...valueB.numberCoupleIdDelete, argDeleteCoupleCategory] }); };` and my state look like this: `const [valueB, setValueB] = useState({ numberCoupleIdDelete: [], });` and my input look like this:`<input type="checkbox" onClick={() => props.deleteСoupleСategory(item.id)}/>`

Comment: //actions.js
`export const deleteСoupleСategory = (argDeleteCoupleCategory) =>
({type:"DELETE_COUPLE_CATEGORY", payload:argDeleteCoupleCategory})`

//reducer.js
`const initialState = {
 numberCoupleIdDelete: []
};

export function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "DELETE_COUPLE_CATEGORY":
    return {...state,numberCoupleIdDelete: [...state.numberCoupleIdDelete, 
 action.payload] }
default:
      return state;
  }
`